# Split Time Off Hours (Working) by Week (Monday - Sunday) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have Time Off data per Employee. I need to split it by Week (Monday - Sunday), but before that, I need to calculate **WORKING** Days Off and Hours per **WORKING** Day Off, so if Time Off starts in the middle of the week (Wednesday for example), we will know, that only Hours for 3 working days (Wednesday, Thursday and Friday) will be assigned to that week.

```
Id     Name       Date Start    Date End   Time Off Hours

1  Tom Holland   2022-04-22    2022-05-06        88.0
```

I was able to exclude Weekends and calculate **Number of WORKING Days Off** and **Hours per WORKING Day Off**.

```
test = {'Id': [1], 'Name': ['Tom Holland'], 'Date Start': ['2022-04-22'], 'Date End': ['2022-05-06'], 'Time Off Hours': [88.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)

time_diff = []

for i in df.index:

    time_diff.append(np.busday_count(df["Date Start"][i], df["Date End"][i], weekmask=[1,1,1,1,1,0,0]) + 1)

df["Days Off (Working)"] = time_diff

df['Hours per Days Off (Working)'] = df["Time Off Hours"] / df["Days Off (Working)"]
```

The output is:

```
Id     Name       Date Start    Date End   Time Off Hours   Days Off (Working)  Hours per Days Off (Working)

1  Tom Holland   2022-04-22    2022-05-06        88.0            11                    8.0
```

And now I need to split and then group this record in 3 records (in this case), because 2022-04-22 and 2022-05-06 date range falls in 3 weeks period (Monday to Sunday):

1. from 2022-04-18 to 2022-04-24 week (1 Working Day Off = 8 Hours)
2. from 2022-04-25 to 2022-05-01 week (5 Working Day Off = 40 Hours)
3. from 2022-05-02 to 2022-05-08 week (5 Working Day Off = 40 Hours)

**Desired output should look similar to that:**

| Id | Name | Week Start | Week End | Days Off (Working) | Hours per Days Off (Working) | Total Off Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom Holland | 2022-04-18 | 2022-04-24 | 1 | 8.0 | 8.0 |
| 1 | Tom Holland | 2022-04-25 | 2022-05-01 | 5 | 8.0 | 40.0 |
| 1 | Tom Holland | 2022-05-02 | 2022-05-08 | 5 | 8.0 | 40.0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most concise way of doing it, but it does the job. First I've created your example df

```py
test = {'Id': [1], 'Name': ['Tom Holland'], 'Date Start': ['2022-04-22'], 'Date End': ['2022-05-06'], 'Time Off Hours': [88.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)
```

Then I've created a helper function that will help me later to calculate the number of working days of each week based also using the `Date Start` and `Date End` in case they start or end before the week star and end

```py
# You could try to use np.select to optimize this part
def get_work_days(row: pd.Series) -> int:
  start = row["Date Start"]
  end = row["Date End"]
  week_start = row["Week Start"]
  week_end = row["Week End"]

  if week_start <= start <= week_end:
    bdays = len(pd.bdate_range(start, week_end))
  elif week_start <= end <= week_end:
    bdays = len(pd.bdate_range(week_start, end))
  elif week_start <= end <= week_end and week_start <= start <= week_end:
    bdays = len(pd.bdate_range(start, end))
  else:
    bdays = len(pd.bdate_range(week_start, week_end))
  
  return bdays
```

And finally the process part to return your desired output

```py
def process_dataframe(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
  # Making sure that these columns are datetime
  df["Date Start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date Start"])
  df["Date End"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date End"])
  # Calculating Working days between date start and date end
  df["Days Off (Working)"] = df.apply(lambda row: len(pd.bdate_range(row["Date Start"], row["Date End"])), axis=1)
  df['Hours per Days Off (Working)'] = df["Time Off Hours"] / df["Days Off (Working)"]
  # Creating Week Start values 
  df["Week Start"] = df.apply(
      lambda row: pd.date_range(
          start=row["Date Start"].to_period("W").start_time, 
          end=row["Date End"].to_period("W").start_time, 
          freq="7D"
    ),
    axis=1
  )
  # Creating Week End values
  df["Week End"] = df.apply(
      lambda row: pd.date_range(
          start=row["Date Start"].to_period("W").end_time, 
          end=row["Date End"].to_period("W").end_time, 
          freq="7D"
    ),
    axis=1
  )
  # Exploding the values, since the way they were created made them as a DatetimeIndex
  # field.
  df = df.explode(["Week Start", "Week End"])
  # Just did that because the Week End had a weird time due to .end_time 
  df["Week End"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Week End"].dt.date)
  df["Week Start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Week Start"].dt.date)
  # Using the helper function to calculate the working days
  df["Days Off (Working)"] = df.apply(get_work_days, axis=1)
  df["Total Off Hours"] = df["Days Off (Working)"] * df["Hours per Days Off (Working)"]
  return df[["Name", "Week Start", "Week End", "Days Off (Working)", "Hours per Days Off (Working)", "Total Off Hours"]]
```

### EDIT

Quick fix in the `get_work_days` function. We need to check if both start and end dates are within the week first and then check the individual dates so the newer version would look like

```py
def get_work_days(row: pd.Series) -> int:
  start = row["Date Start"]
  end = row["Date End"]
  week_start = row["Week Start"]
  week_end = row["Week End"]
 
  if week_start <= end <= week_end and week_start <= start <= week_end:
    bdays = len(pd.bdate_range(start, end))
  elif week_start <= start <= week_end:
    bdays = len(pd.bdate_range(start, week_end))
  elif week_start <= end <= week_end:
    bdays = len(pd.bdate_range(week_start, end))
  else:
    bdays = len(pd.bdate_range(week_start, week_end))
  
  return bdays
```

Comment: Wow, that works as expected. 
Last question, I have a list of holidays, that need to be excluded from WORKING days.

holidays = ['2021-01-01','2021-05-31','2021-07-05','2021-09-06','2021-11-25','2021-11-26','2021-12-24', '2021-12-27', '2021-12-31', '2022-05-30', '2022-07-04','2022-09-05', '2022-11-24', '2022-11-25', '2022-12-23', '2022-12-26']. How can I implement it the code you provided? I usually excluding them in the np.busday_count part, but you are not using it. 

Thank You.

Comment: I did some testing, and it works incorrectly in some cases.

test = {'Id': [1], 'Name': ['Tom Holland'], 'Date Start': ['2022-02-08'], 'Date End': ['2022-02-08'], 'Time Off Hours': [4.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)

In this case output is 4 working days, but actually is 1

Comment: @Yara1994 you're right, I add an edit with the fix. Regarding the holidays you could add a checker to look for the holidays inside the generated range in the get_work_days and to the lambda function used to get the total working days

Comment: Thank You, @Eduardo Pacheco.
Actually, I found the way to exclude holidays. freq='C', holidays = holidays needs to be added to the each pd.bdate_range() in both functions. And then condition needs to be added if df["Days Off (Working)"] == 0 (if time off, 1 day only, was requested on holiday), then df['Hours per Days Off (Working)'] = df["Time Off Hours"] / 1, otherewise df['Hours per Days Off (Working)'] = df["Time Off Hours"] / df["Days Off (Working)"].
Again, thank you very much for help!